# delete nodes at random in an adjacency matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I have some problem testing [Barabassi albert scale free graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model).
I want to delete nodes at random to see how robust is this model for deletion of nodes (randomely)?
I have adjacency matrix `adj`. How can I delete nodes at random in matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26606682/1714410) is quite good, but I have some reservations

1. `randi` can return the same index more than once. For example

   ```
   >> randi(10,1,5)
   ans =
   6     3    10     6     2
   ```

   returned `6` twice. Therefore it may reduce **less** than `n` elements from the matrix.
2. It is more efficient to select what elements should stay in the matrix than constructing a full matrix and discard elements from it: you actually copy large portions of the matrix at each command.

Therefore, my solution would be using [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
N = size(adj,1); %// current number of nodes
toKeep = N - n; %// n is number to remove
idx = randsample( N, toKeep ); %// sample WITHOUT replacement
newadj = adj( idx, idx ); %// copy only the relevant elements
```

Comment: You are absolutely rigth, I wrote it without htinking it too much, and I got short! thanks for the good answers :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** [@Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630351/1714410) is better than mine and shows the errors in mine. Thats the real good answer.

If I am not wrong: and adjacency matrix is a `Npoints X Npoints` matrix with each node showing wich node is adjacent to.

I guess if you want to delete random points you need to delete rows and colums for that point.

```
% n is number of points that you want to delete
% adj is the adjacency matrix
idx=randi(size(adj,1),n)
newadj=adj;
newadj(idx,:)=[];
newadj(:,idx)=[];
```

Comment: i get this error :The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

Comment: on this: auxadj=adj(idx,:)=[];
        newadj=auxadj(:,idx)=[];

Comment: @AnderBiguri - down vote, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26630351/1714410) for reasons.

Comment: @arashams Actually, you shoudl see Shais answer as he is conpletely  right.